# Returning a Cursor from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor

Hi i need to return a `CURSOR` from a `STORED PROCEDURE`  i approached like this

```
create proc pps @return_cursor cursor VARYING OUTPUT As
DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR
SELECT id FROM table_name
```

Now my problem is to capture the return Cursor

```
DECLARE cur_ret  CURSOR
```

> cur_ret = exec pps

but execute approach give an error

**My problem is How to Return a CURSOR from a Stored procedure and capture it**

Comment: Sounds like your doing it wrong Sudantha. You should not need to return a cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out it can be do like this

> create proc pps @ret_cur cursor
>   VARYING OUTPUT As DECLARE @CURx CURSOR
>   SET @CURx= CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM
>   users1
>
> DECLARE @CrsrVar CURSOR;
>
> **EXEC PPS @ret_cur=@CrsrVar OUTPUT**

Comment: the cursor should be also open before return !

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Using the cursor Data Type in an OUTPUT Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175498.aspx)